# Append comment replies based on parent ID

Tags: php

Initially I have all of the comments stored in the array `$commentsrow`, which has arrays as values (containing the comment info such as username, date, etc).

```
  foreach($commentsrow as $comment){

    // variables are set, including this one:

    $parent_id = $comment['parent_id'];

  ?> 

  // HTML is here


  <?php }

  ?>
```

So this works for comments with no parent (i.e. not a reply), but how would I actually "append" replies to the parent based on its ID?

Comment: your question is not clear. please clearly tell it by showing actual full code and your expected outcome. thanks

Comment: Image: http://puu.sh/iJSIW/0f61172d76.png

Comment: what you want? not clear. also put things in your question not in comment

Comment: The code I put up there is fine for the top-level comments, but I'm asking how to append all the replies to the comment. e.g. Top-level comment 1 has 10 replies.. so would I put another foreach loop in the first foreach loop to "append" all of them to it?

Comment: show your full code then. is that replies are in the same table or in different table? how you are going to get them? Please show your full code

Comment: I have no table set up. The divs just sit within each other. like this `<div><div></div></div>`.  I would show the full code but it's too much / mostly irrelevant. Do I make another query to the database within the first foreach loop to retrieve the current $comment from the foreach loop's replies?

Comment: I just realised you meant database table, not HTML table (I think). All comments are in the same table, with a column called `parent_id` which is equal to the `comment_id`, and all the comments have those.

Comment: Use `JOIN` in query and try to get all replies for a single comment. it will give you relaxation from all  complexity.